# Compiling swift code to 32 bit object files

Tags: swift, debian

I recently got interested in the swift programming language and i wanted to see if i could integrate it into an existing project of mine which is a 32 bit microkernel

The first thing i tried was to compile it into a 32 bit object file but i didn't know how so i searched google for about 3 hours and i could not find anything helpful. This is the code i am trying to compile

```swift
@_cdecl("swift_func")
func swift_f(x: Int) -> Int {
    return x-10
}
```

I expected to compile the file into a 32 bit ELF object but i can't seem to find the right arguments for that

NB: I am on debian linux

Answer (score 2):

So i figured it out, hopefully this can help others

```sh
swiftc -emit-library -emit-object -Xcc "-m32" -o hello.o hello.swift
```

So what was needed was telling swift to make it a static object file then pass `-m32` to the underlying clang compiler which makes it a 32 bit object file